# Angularjs directive elem.id = $index not its actual index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an angularjs directive to focus a particular input in a list if the element's id matches a particular number.

My html

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="line in lines">
            {{$index}} <input focus-it="" id="{{$index}}" tabIndex="{{$index}}" type="text" ng-model="line.data" ng-keypress="keyPress($event, $index, line.data)" value="{{line.data}}"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

My directive:

```
app.directive('focusIt', function() {
return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        console.log(elem[0].id);
        console.log(scope.focus);
        if (elem[0].id == scope.focus) {
            elem[0].focus();
        }
    }
}
});
```

The console logs:

```
{{$index}}
0
```

Why is the id of the element being shown this way? And how can i make it so that that comparison works?

Overall what I am trying to do is create new elements and focus them dynamically.

Comment: Try `attrs.id` instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$timeout` to let angular render the id expression first ... otherwise you need to use `$eval` on the attribute to evaluate it

```
app.directive('focusIt', function($timeout) {
return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      $timeout(function(){
          console.log(elem[0].id);
          console.log(scope.focus);
          if (elem[0].id == scope.focus) {
              elem[0].focus();
          }
      });
    }
}
});
```